# Is there a convention to warn user that a passed parameter will be modified?

Tags: python, pep8

In python and (optionally) pep8, is there a conventional a way to signal to the user that a passed parameter (e.g. a `dict`) will be modified by the function being called?

Comment: conventionally, functions should not modify the objects being passed in.

Comment: The name of the function should make it obvious, or at least cast enough doubt to make you check the docs.  That's the "practical" advice at least

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning `None` from the function is used as an indicator that the object may have been modified in-place. For example, `sort()` returns `None`, while `sorted()` returns the a sorted copy of the input list, and leaves the input itself alone (though, in fact, `sort()` is a method on a list).

It's not the best indicator: having good documentation and spelling it out near the top of a doc-string is probably better (for example as [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) does).
But it is what built-in and standard library functions seem to do.

---

Brief note on some other libraries: NumPy's `sort` returns and does not modify in-place, so it has different behaviour compared to the built-in `sort` function. Pandas functions & methods often have an `inplace` boolean argument, which by default tends to be `False`, so by default, a modified copy is returned.

Comment: Note, usually this is for *methods*, although, the standard library does include a module which does this with functions `heapq`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga perhaps, but the example given is for two equivalent built-in functions, one modifying in-place and one not modifying in-place but returning.

Comment: No, one is a method on `list` objets, the other is a free function. Normally, free functions should not mutate the objects passed in to them, same with methods, so `some_object.some_method(some_arg)`, then it is usually bad to have `some_method` modify `some_arg`... of course, *internal* state is often mutable. I'm not disagreeing with your answer, though, I upvoted.

Comment: Ah, yes, I mistook `list.sort`; I don't actually use it often.